# Creating Kotlin coroutine Deferred object that emitts listener callback results

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlinx.coroutines

I´m currently switching from RxJava to Kotlin coroutines in a project, replacing all the Single and Observable return types by coroutine aquivalents. I´m still struggling with the following construct: An interface (e.g. of a repository) offers data query access and returns a RxJava Single. The implementation creates a Single object with Single.create and emits the result with onSuccess/onError. Now what the implementation needs to do to retrieve the data is creating a listener with callbacks and registering that listener to something. The callbacks of that created listener would then call onSuccess/onError on the selfmade Single. E.g. using firebase (although my question is not firebase specific):

```
interface Repository {
    fun getData(query: Query): Single<DataSnapshot?>
}

fun getData(query: Query): Single<DataSnapshot?> = Single.create { emitter ->
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError?) {
            emitter.onError(Exception())
        }

        override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot?) {
            emitter.onSuccess(data)
        }
    })
}
```

Now what I want to have instead is the interface method returning coroutine Deferred. How does the implementation have to be created so that there also can be registered a listener with callbacks, whose results then will be delivered by the Deferred? I don´t see a way with these coroutine builders like async, launch etc. doing what onSuccess/onError would do.

```
interface Repository {
    fun getData(query: Query): Deferred<DataSnapshot?>
}
```

Comment: If you are switching from Rx to coroutines, then you should go from Single to suspending functions:

    suspend fun getData(query: Query): DataSnapshot?

As a rule of thumb, you should not have functions that return Deferred.

Comment: Ok, I´ll do so, but still don´t know how to do the implementation then, how I get from listener and callbacks to the required return value DataSnapshot of the suspend function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My suggestion is as follows:

```
interface Repository {
    suspend fun getData(query: Query): Result<DataSnapshot>
}
```

where Result could be a sealed class with Success and Error cases:

```
sealed class Result<T> {
    class Success<T>(result: T) : Result<T>()
    class Error<T>(error: String) : Result<T>()
}
```

This way, in the implementation side of getData you can do:

```
return Success(yourData)
```

or

```
return Error("Something went wrong")
```

In general when dealing with coroutines you should avoid returning the deferreds and try to use them "as synchronous methods".

Edit:
Now that I understand the problem I hope this helps solve it:

```
//This is as generic as it gets, you could use it on any Query, no need to retype it
suspend fun Query.await(): DataSnapshot = suspendCoroutine{cont ->
    addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError?) {
            cont.resumeWithException(error?: Exception("Unknown Error"))
        }

        override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot?) {
            if(data != null){
                cont.resume(data)
            } else {
                cont.resumeWithException(Exception("Null data"))
            }

        }
    })
}
//this is your actual implementation
suspend fun getData(query: Query):DataSnapshot =
        query.await()
```

This code is assuming DatabaseError extends Exception or Throwable. If not you would need to create a wrapper type for it or use my original solution and use the regular resume in both cases.

Comment: Still not solving the problem. I cannot return anything out of the callback methods intended as return type for the suspend function. That´s why the Single.create construct is done how it is done in the first place

Comment: Now I understand the problem better. Sadly I don't have the time right now to explain how to convert from this type of situations to coroutines. But there are two talks about coroutines in the 2017 kotlin conf that explain them in depth and the second talk explains how to do this kind of thing.
https://youtu.be/_hfBv0a09Jc
https://youtu.be/YrrUCSi72E8

Answer (score 0):

I think closest thing of what I´m looking for would be ReceiveChannel. Came up with this solution:

```
override fun getData(query: Query): ReceiveChannel<Datasnapshot?> = GlobalScope.produce {
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot?) {
            launch { send(data) } }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError?) {
            throw Exception()
        }
    })
}
```

Not sure if this is kind of overkill and there would be way better ones, suggestions welcome